# Python Selenium - Extract words using Safari and csvWriter - Empty variable and container -

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, safari

Now I am having an issue where the next page is not loading completely for me to take the information down fully and the script is coming up with a NoMatchingElement error halfway through. I tried adding a WebDriverWait as shown below in the code, but it is not working. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
import sys
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

# default path to file to store data
path_to_file = "/Users/Dan/Desktop/reviews.csv"

# default number of scraped pages
num_page = 1939

# default tripadvisor website of hotel or things to do (attraction/monument) 
url = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g187791-d192285-Reviews-Colosseum-Rome_Lazio.html"

# if you pass the inputs in the command line
if (len(sys.argv) == 4):
    path_to_file = sys.argv[1]
    num_page = int(sys.argv[2])
    url = sys.argv[3]

# import the webdriver
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get(url)

# open the file to save the review
csvFile = open(path_to_file, 'a', encoding="utf-8")
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

# change the value inside the range to save more or less reviews
data=[]
for i in range(0, num_page):

    # expand the review
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='tabs-1']/div[2]/a[@accesskey='n']")))
    container = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='tabs-1']/div[3]/table/tbody")
    for con in container:
        name = con.find_element_by_xpath(".//tr[2]/td").text.replace("Sponsor Name:","")
        start = con.find_element_by_xpath(".//tr[1]/td[3]").text.replace("Start Date*: ","")
        data.append((name,start))
        df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Start'])
        df.to_csv('/Users/Dan/Desktop/reviews.csv', index = False)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tabs-1']/div[2]/a[@accesskey='n']").click()
    

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how to do it with csv writer but I know that you can do it like so. Just append to 2d list and then write to csv file.

```
driver.get("https://www.clinicaltrialsregister.eu/ctr-search/search?query=")
container = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='tabs-1']/div[3]/table/tbody")
data=[]
for con in container:
    name = con.find_element_by_xpath(".//tr[2]/td").text
    start = con.find_element_by_xpath(".//tr[1]/td[3]").text
    data.append((name,start))
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Start'])
#print(df)
df.to_csv('/Users/Dan/Desktop/reviews.csv', index = False)
```

Import

```
import pandas as pd
```

[image: Example output]

Comment: I think there is a way to just to print to the csv after this in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56025046/2d-list-to-csv-by-column without df. But this way has a way to add columns.

Comment: Any chance you could assist with another issue? I revised the above to take into account the new question.

Comment: Always keeps the 2 df lines out of the for loop. First collect the data and then write to csv.